# How to mock an observable value from a service Angular 7?

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

I have been trying to write unit tests for my Angular component. Currently in my service call to get the data for my component I have an observable that is given true once the call has finished. This observable to subscribed to in my component so the component knows when the call has bee completed. I have managed to mock the call for data in my component but I am struggling to find a way to mock the single observable value.

All the questions on SO that I can find are all about mocking a function call from the service in the component but none that I can find are about mocking a single observable.

Here is my function call in the service. As you can see the observable is given a new value once the `finalize` function runs:

```js
  public getSmallInfoPanel(key: string): BehaviorSubject<InfoPanelResponse> {

    if (key) {
      this.infoPanel = new BehaviorSubject<InfoPanelResponse>(null);

      this.http.get(`${this.apiUrl}api/Panels/GetInfoPanel/${key}`).pipe(
          retry(3),
          finalize(() => {
            this.hasLoadedSubject.next(true);
          }))
        .subscribe((x: InfoPanelResponse) => this.infoPanel.next(x));
    }
    return this.infoPanel;
  }
```

Here is how I created the `Observable` in the service:

```js
 private hasLoadedSubject: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
 public hasLoadedObs: Observable<boolean> = this.hasLoadedSubject.asObservable();
```

Then in my component I subscribe to the `Observable` created from the `BehaviourSubject`:

```js
public hasLoaded: boolean;

  ngOnInit() {

    this.infoPanelSmallService.hasLoadedObs.subscribe(z => this.hasLoaded = z);

  }
```

When I run `ng test` the component test fails because it does not know what `hasLoadedObs` is so it cannot subscribe to it.

Let me know if I can provide more info. Thank you.

**UPDATE 1**

```js
describe('InformationPanelSmallComponent', () => {
  let component: InformationPanelSmallComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<InformationPanelSmallComponent>;

  let mockInfoPanelService;
  let mockInfoPanel: InfoPanel;
  let mockInfoPanelResponse: InfoPanelResponse;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule,
        FontAwesomeModule,
        HttpClientTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [InformationPanelSmallComponent, CmsInfoDirective],
      providers: [
        { provide: InfoPanelSmallService, useValue: mockInfoPanelService }
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {

    mockInfoPanel = {
      Title: 'some title',
      Heading: 'some heading',
      Description: 'some description',
      ButtonText: 'some button text',
      ButtonUrl: 'some button url',
      ImageUrl: 'some image url',
      Key: 'test-key',
      SearchUrl: '',
      VideoUrl: ''
    }

    mockInfoPanelResponse = {
      InfoPanel: mockInfoPanel
    }

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(InformationPanelSmallComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;

    mockInfoPanelService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['getSmallInfoPanel']);

    component = new InformationPanelSmallComponent(mockInfoPanelService);

    component.key = "test-key"

  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
  //TO DO
  it('should get info panel from info panel service', () => {
    mockInfoPanelService.getSmallInfoPanel.and.returnValue(of(mockInfoPanelResponse));
    component.ngOnInit();

    expect(mockInfoPanelService.getSmallInfoPanel).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(component.infoPanel).toEqual(mockInfoPanel);
  });
});
```

Comment: add a spy for it: `spyOnProperty(component.infoPanelSmallService, 'hasLoadedObs', 'get').and.returnValue(of(true))`

Comment: @enno.void It still says `hasLoadedObs` is undefined.

Comment: @DanielBailey Are you mocking the service, or do are you providing your original service in your TestBed?

Comment: can you share your test file

Comment: @TzannetosPhilippakos  I added my test file.

Comment: @FatehMohamed Added test file.

Comment: Have you tried to create the spy before you mock the service? Just declare it like const mockInfoPanelService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['getSmallInfoPanel', 'hasLoadedObs']);

Comment: And then later mockInfoPanelService.hasLoadedObs.and.returnValue(of(true)); or mockInfoPanelService.hasLoadedObs = of(true); because 'returnValue' is to mock functions not values (observables in this case).

Comment: @RuiMarques I tried this: `mockCarouselService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['getCarouselSmallSlides','hasLoadedObs']);` and then later I used: `mockCarouselService.hasLoadedObs = of(true);`. However it is still returning: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasLoadedObs' of undefined`

Comment: @RuiMarques as well as: `this.carouselSmallService.hasLoadedObs.subscribe is not a function`

Comment: You are doing "component = new InformationPanelSmallComponent(mockInfoPanelService);" which overwrites what is done by "component = fixture.componentInstance;". You should initialise the component in one way or the other, not both, because one is overwritten. I would keep the latter which is the recommended way to test components.

Comment: @RuiMarques I have tried what you have said and I removed the `fixture.detectChanges()` from the `beforeEach` function. Now I just get the error: `Cannot read property 'hasLoadedObs' of undefined` even though I have defined the `mockCarouselService`?

Comment: Ok its starting to get weird :P Can you try to reproduce your issue in a stackblitz.com or at least update the code in this question?

Comment: @RuiMarques I will try make a stackblitz and will send you a message when it is done :)

Comment: @RuiMarques after some more testing it looks like it had to do with the order I was putting things into the test file and mocking things from the service. I will post an answer now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found that it had to do with the order I was mocking the service and creating the component. I also used `TestBed.overrideProvider` which is something different to what I was using above. This is the end resulting test file:

```js
describe('InformationPanelSmallComponent', () => {
  let component: InformationPanelSmallComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<InformationPanelSmallComponent>;

  let mockInfoPanelService;
  let mockInfoPanel: InfoPanel;
  let mockInfoPanelResponse: InfoPanelResponse;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    mockInfoPanelService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['getSmallInfoPanel', 'hasLoadedObs']);

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule,
        FontAwesomeModule,
        HttpClientTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [InformationPanelSmallComponent, CmsInfoDirective, UrlRedirectDirective],
      providers: [
        { provide: 'BASE_URL', useValue: '/' },
        { provide: 'API_URL', useValue: '/' }
      ]
    })

    TestBed.overrideProvider(InfoPanelSmallService, { useValue: mockInfoPanelService });

    TestBed.compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {

    mockInfoPanel = {
      Title: 'some title',
      Heading: 'some heading',
      Description: 'some description',
      ButtonText: 'some button text',
      ButtonUrl: 'some button url',
      ImageUrl: 'some image url',
      Key: 'test-key',
      SearchUrl: '',
      VideoUrl: ''
    }

    mockInfoPanelResponse = {
      InfoPanel: mockInfoPanel
    }

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(InformationPanelSmallComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;

    mockInfoPanelService.getSmallInfoPanel.and.returnValue(of(mockInfoPanelResponse));
    mockInfoPanelService.hasLoadedObs = of(true);

    component.key = "test-key"

    fixture.detectChanges();

  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  describe('ngOnInit', () => {
    it('should get info panel from info panel service', () => {
      expect(component.hasLoaded).toEqual(true);
      expect(mockInfoPanelService.getSmallInfoPanel).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(component.infoPanel).toEqual(mockInfoPanel);
    });

    it('should get loaded is true from service', () => {
      expect(component.hasLoaded).toEqual(true);
    });
  });
});
```

I then got no more errors and the tests actually functioned correctly. Thanks @RuiMarques and others for all the input.

Comment: Re-assigning mockInfoPanelService.hasLoadedObs to be an observable *after* you just defined it as a spy with `jasmine.createSpyObj` seems weird, you are overriding the spy with the observable, so what's the point of having created the spy in the first place?
This works, but i found the answer not satisfying, another approach I found would be to use the "stubbing" approach, then you can simply define spies and have these return the values you want: https://shashankvivek-7.medium.com/testing-a-component-with-stub-services-and-spies-in-jasmine-1428d4242a49